# placing a large Image into an imageview using picasso

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am using the navigationView layout for my navigation drawer as shown below:

activity_main.xml:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
             android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="start"
             app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
             app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header_layout"
             android:background="@color/colour8"/>
```

As you can see there is a header layout applied (nav_drawer_header_layout), inside that layout there is a an imageview which i am trying to place a large image.

MainActivity.java :

```
 //Initailise the navigation view
   NavigationView navView =       (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view); 

  //Cast the imageView holder that the large is placed in 
  ImageView header = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.header_navigation_drawer_header_image);

 //Dimensions
 int imageViewWidth = header.getWidth(); 
 int imageViewHeight = header.getHeight();    

        //Scale image into header with picasso 
        Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.food)
                          .fit()
                          .centerCrop()
                          .resize(imageViewWidth,imageViewHeight)
                          .into(header);
```

Then I get the following logcat error:

```
dRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.nazim.kmapp, PID: 18538
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nazim.kmapp/com.example.nazim.kmapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
   at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
   at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
   at com.example.nazim.kmapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:216)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5976)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

The issue seems to be with the imageView is null,

Solution with explanation will be much appreciated.... 
Thanks for your help in advance!!!!

Comment: Worked out the problem, I inflated the header view using getLayoutInflater(), then attaching view to the navigation view as one of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `app:headerLayout` attribute in your `NavigationView` like :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
         android:background="@color/colour8"/>
```

Then inflate your header layout in `Activity` like :

```
//you can use LinearLayout, RelativeLayout ,FrameLayout etc. which you are using in your header layout
LinearLayout  headerLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_drawer_header_layout);
```

Now you are able to get any `View` in your header layout like :

```
ImageView header = (ImageView)headerLayout .findViewById(R.id.header_navigation_drawer_header_image);
```

> You are getting `IllegalArgumentException : Target must not be null` which means your `ImageView` is null. Because it isn't in the `Activity`'s layout. It's in the `NavigationView`'s layout.

Answer (score 0):

*Replace this code with*

```
//Cast the imageView holder that the large is placed in 
ImageView header = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.header_navigation_drawer_header_image);
```

*This*

```
 //Initailise the navigation view
 NavigationView navView =       (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
//Cast the imageView holder that the large is placed in 
 ImageView header = (ImageView) navView.findViewById(R.id.header_navigation_drawer_header_image);
```

This is because your image view is inside navView fragment android intends to find you layout element inside your layout but there is no imageView inside it therefore it returns null so must say where to find the view with this `navView.findViewByID()`.

Comment: Tried your code but didn't work, getting the same error

Comment: please check if the id (R.id.header_navigation_drawer_header_image) for image view is correct / try to run after rebuilding your project